# Cargar distinta información en la misma página de una plantilla con WordPress php

Tags: php, wordpress, url, template, parametros

tengo un problemilla con php y Wordpress...

Existe una web en la que se puede mirar información sobre pueblos y dos páginas web cada una con su respectiva plantilla en WordPress. Una es una gran tabla con todos los pueblos y la otra página es a la que se accede haciendo click en cualquier fila de esta tabla y muestra la información relativa al pueblo en concreto seleccionado.

Para saber la información de qué pueblo se debe cargar en la segunda página, en la primera página, al hacer click en un pueblo, se guarda el id de ese pueblo en la variable de sesión `$_SESSION["id_pueblo"]` y en la segunda página se recupera, sirviendo los datos.

Entonces, la url de la segunda página es **SIEMPRE** la misma para todos los pueblos. Es una plantilla que sirve la información de acuerdo a la variable `$_SESSION["id_pueblo"]`.

```
if(isset($_SESSION['id_pueblo'])) {
        $idPueblo = $_SESSION['id_pueblo']; 
}

$result = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("select * from pueblo where id_pueblo=%d", $idPueblo));
```

El problema es el siguiente: es totalmente inútil copiar en enlace de la segunda página, la que muestra la información del pueblo y pasársela a otra persona para que vea dicha información, ya que la variable `$_SESSION["id_pueblo"]` en ese caso no tiene nada almacenado, por lo que no se muestra el detalle de ningún pueblo.

Quiero saber si puedo resolver esto de alguna manera. Obviamente no quiero hacer una plantilla por cada pueblo en WordPress. Se me había ocurrido algo así como poner en la url como parámetro el nombre del pueblo pero, evidentemente, a la hora de cargar la segunda página, cargar la url sin dicho parámetro para que funcione bien la segunda página pero no lo estoy consiguiendo.

Muchas gracias!

Comment: Pon más contexto en el isset pues no se ve que estas haciendo alli ni que ocurre si no entra (es decir, el $idPueblo ya venia predefinido de antes?)... por otra parte, supongo que puedes usar $_GET['id_pueblo'] del mismo modo, con un condicional identico al que ya tienes (si es que eso es un condicional, no esta completo!), a continuación del mismo. Y luego darles las url asi:   `https://www.midominio.com/pueblos/?id_pueblo=123` para que entre en ese condicional y asigne la variable `$idPueblo = $_GET['id_pueblo'];` antes del prepare

Comment: @masterguru Perdona me olvidé de escribir el if delante de isset. Este if es lo primero que mira la segunda página, antes no hay nada. La página tenía hardcodeado un id para que el $result devolviese algo en caso de que en la sesión no hubiese ningún id de ningún pueblo y para que la segunda página no estuviera en blanco.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pues dada tu explicación en los comentarios, prueba con esto:

```
if(isset($_GET['id_pueblo'])) {
    $idPueblo = $_GET['id_pueblo']; 
} else {
    if(isset($_SESSION['id_pueblo'])) {
        $idPueblo = $_SESSION['id_pueblo']; 
    } else {
        $idPueblo = "valorhardcodeado";
    }
}

$result = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("select * from pueblo where id_pueblo=%d", $idPueblo));
```

De este modo prevalece el GET sobre el SESSION y en caso de no hallar ninguno de los dos usará el hardcodeado para que no te de error la consulta por variable indefinida.

Luego puedes usar urls del tipo GET de este modo:

```
https://www.midominio.com/pueblos/?id_pueblo=123
```

para acceder a esa página directamente con el valor del pueblo pasado en el parámetro **id_pueblo** de la url. Evidentemente cámbialo por tu escenario y script y url correcto, que no se cual es realmente.

Comment: Algo así serviría muchas gracias!